# Very confusing Abstract Class, need guidance

Tags: class, inheritance, abstract

I missed a few CS classes, namely the ones going over topics such as polymorphism, inheritence, and abstract classes. I'm not asking you to do my homework but I have no idea where to even start to get further guidance, so giving me a skeleton or something would help me greatly, I'm so confused.

So the problem is to create an employee abstract class with two subclasses, permanentEmployee and TempEmployee.I must store information such as name,department,and salary in these subclasses and then order them according to how the user wants them ordered. I know I start out like this

```
 public abstract class Employee
  {
  }
  public class TempEmployee extends Employee
  {
\\variables such as name, salary, etc, here?
  }
  public class PermEmployee extends Employee
  {
\\here too?
  }
```

but I have no idea how to store variables in there much less access them later for ordering and displaying,. Please guidance.

Comment: I'm so used to ADA that it made me hate Java for how confusing it can be

Comment: A basic introduction to Java will cover how to add variables to a class, as well as create getters and setters for those variables.  As for sorting, there are many sorting algorithms you could use.  Also intro-level stuff.  Not to sound harsh, but if this is where you're stuck then you should really be consulting your introductory course materials or a basic tutorial on Java.

Comment: I'm not asking for help how to sort, I can do that

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is an example of class-level data members in Java, this should help:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int someInt;

    public int getSomeInt() {
        return this.someInt;
    }

    public void setSomeInt(int someInt) {
        this.someInt = someInt;
    }
}
```

Regarding polymorphism, be aware that *methods* are polymorphic, but *values* are not.  As you place values and methods (getters and setters) in your base class and derived classes, I encourage you to experiment with these concepts thoroughly.  Try moving the entire value/getter/setter to the base class, try moving just the value but not the getter/setter, try putting the value in both and the getter/setter in both, etc.  See how it behaves.

Make sure that any value/method/etc. that you put in your base class is applicable to *all* derived classes.  If there's ever an exception to that rule, then you would need to move that member out of the base class and into only derived classes where it applies.  Note that you can have a complex hierarchy of base classes to accommodate this if needed.

---

When it comes time to access these members for sorting/display/etc., consuming code would use the getters/setters.  For example:

```
SomeClass myInstance = new SomeClass();
myInstance.setSomeInt(2);
System.out.println(myInstance.getSomeInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language you working with, but as it has "extends" I am sure you are not working with c# or CSharp, it can be Java. So I would recommend you to go for [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_abstraction.htm). This particular article has abstraction described here.

Just to make it easy for you, in Interface and abstraction we always create a structure or the base, it has all the common things defined or declared (Obviously interface has only methods and no variables can be declared inside it).

So as said, in above example, EmployeeId, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress ...etc should be defined in the base class that is Abstract Base class Employee, But in TempEmployee you can have a criteria such as EmpTermPeriod, EmpContractRenewalDate, EmpExternalPayrollCompanyName (Have made names long and self descriptive) and PermEmployee to have fields like EmpJoiningDate, EmpConfirmationDate, EmpGraduityDate...etc. 
I hope it helps.